# Open TTY to use with execlp and dup

Tags: c++, pipe, fork, tty

I am trying to create a minimal code to use pipe/fork/execlp.
So far so good, I am using execlp with bash -c, so if I do.

```
echo asd |./a.out cat 
> asd
```

So it is working as expected.
But if I try to use anything that needs a TTY, it does not work.
Like ./a.out vim, I get "Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal"
And the vim that was open does not works as expected.

I tried to find on the internet an example on how to open a TTY, the only one that I found was:
http://www.danlj.org/lad/src/minopen.c

My Code, so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

typedef struct pCon{
    int fout[2];
    int fin[2];
    int fd[2];
    int pid1, pid2;
} connectionManager;

std::string command = "";

/*
 * Implementation
 */
void childFork(connectionManager *cm);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int size;

    if(argc < 2) exit(1);
    else command = argv[1];

    connectionManager *cm = new connectionManager;
    pipe(cm->fd);
    if((cm->pid1 = fork()) == -1)exit(1);
    if (cm->pid1 == 0)
    {
        const unsigned int RCVBUFSIZE = 2000;
        char echoString[RCVBUFSIZE];

        while((size = read(fileno(stdin),echoString,RCVBUFSIZE)) > 0)
            write(cm->fd[1], echoString, size);
        close(cm->fd[1]);
     }
    else
        childFork(cm);
  return 0;
}


void childFork(connectionManager *cm){
    char *buffer = new char[2000];
    int size;
    close(cm->fd[1]);
    dup2(cm->fd[0], 0);
    close(cm->fd[0]);
    pipe(cm->fout);

    if((cm->pid2 = fork()) == -1)exit(1);
    if (cm->pid2 == 0)
    {
        close(cm->fout[0]);
        int returnCode = execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", command.c_str(), NULL);
        if(returnCode!=0)
            std::cerr << "Error starting the bash program" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        close(cm->fout[1]);
        while((size = read(cm->fout[0], buffer, 2000 )) > 0 )
            write(fileno(stdout), buffer, size);
    }
}
```

I tried to keep the minimal necessary code to make it work.
Is there any way to implement TTY on this code, I know that does not seems to be such trivial task.
Can someone help me with that?

I also tried to open the tty and dup it, but no luck so far.

Comment: Which i/o channel of the forked process do you plan to connect to the TTY screen and TTY keyboard (usually std::cout and std::cin)?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN I suppose that i need both, In that code I want, in the end, to be able to open something like a VIM, without problems.

Comment: Check this question: https://superuser.com/questions/336016/invoking-vi-through-find-xargs-breaks-my-terminal-why, so you may refer to xargs's source code to check how it manipulate `stdin` with `-o` option.

Comment: Because your tty's  stdin and stdout go to the terminal for user interaction, maybe consider launching gnome-terminal (or alternatives), with option --command=STRING.  STRING identifies the editor of your choice, and any parameters (file name).  In gnome-terminal command tou can also specify geometry, window title, and working directory.  You code snippet shows fork, which is fine, or you might use one of the exec family, I like popen.

Comment: Humm, my problem can be reproduced with ssh localhost "bash", it does not allocate a TTY, but ssh localhost dows work. This program in the end is an "ssh", I removed a lot of the code. How does SSH implements the TTY, does it needs another program to do so. Regarding popen, I cannot use, because you can only redirect stdin or stdout. This scenario above is just an example, I want to be able to use stuffs like tar -zcvf - Folder | ./a.out "tar -xvf -". Which so far works fine, but if I need a terminal everything stop working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use pseudo terminal. You can use opentty. For your purpose you can use forkpty which combines pty with fork. I've created a small example for you. About the same as your program, just it works. I've kept it simple, so I don't handle the terminal control characters.

```
#include <pty.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc<1) return 1;

    int master;
    pid_t pid = forkpty(&master, NULL, NULL, NULL);    // opentty + login_tty + fork

    if (pid < 0) {
        return 1; // fork with pseudo terminal failed
    }

    else if (pid == 0) {   // child
        char *args[] = { argv[1], argv[2], NULL };  // prg + 1 argument

        execvp(argv[1], args);  // run the program given in first param
    }

    else {   // parent
        struct termios tios;
        tcgetattr(master, &tios);
        tios.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL);
        tcsetattr(master, TCSAFLUSH, &tios);

        while(1) {
            fd_set read_fd, write_fd, err_fd;

            FD_ZERO(&read_fd);
            FD_ZERO(&write_fd);
            FD_ZERO(&err_fd);
            FD_SET(master, &read_fd);
            FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &read_fd);

            select(master+1, &read_fd, &write_fd, &err_fd, NULL);

            if (FD_ISSET(master, &read_fd))
            {
                char ch;
                int c;
                if (c=read(master, &ch, 1) != -1)    // read from program
                    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &ch, c);    // write to tty
                else
                    break;    // exit when end of communication channel with program
            }

            if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &read_fd))
            {
                char ch;
                int c=read(STDIN_FILENO, &ch, 1);   // read from tty
                write(master, &ch, c);              // write to program
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For compiling use -lutil .
While running a new tty device appears in /dev/pts .
vim accepts it as a terminal.

Comment: Nice, it works. Just some questions, if there is a website or a place where I can get those answers from it would also be awesome. 1. Using examples like echo asd | ./a.out cat does not closes the program, should i implement a special code on the STDIN_FILENO?. The vim does not resize the terminal area, is that expected. And last, how do I implement treatment for special terminal characters, is there a place where i have the list and how those should be implemented, is there a special scenario for each one of those?

Comment: Which answers do you mean? echo asd | ./a.out cat   should not close the program. If you start cat, and type asd, it will not close the program cat. It will be closed if you hit enter, then CTRL-d. So   echo asd^M^D | ./a.out cat   should do what you meant here.  ^M^D is written so: CTRL-v,ENTER,CTRL-v,CTRL-d .  Yes, in normal case, vim asks the terminal for its parameters. You can set window size for your pseudo terminal. Eg. struct winsize winp = {10,10}; pid_t pid = forkpty(&master, NULL, NULL, &winp);

Comment: Of course, if you want, you can implement the use of special chars. Just look for ansi, vt100, vt220, xterm, etc. docs. It will be not one place, because there are more terminal types.

Comment: if you do echo asd | cat it will write "asd" close the program. Just cat does not closes it. But I will look into it.